# Wordpress mysql issue - open_basedir restriction in effect

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I just a wordpress web from a test hosting to the clients hosting. Both hosted by the same provider, however, the new page is showing a php error message in main navigation menu (http://www.marianrehak.net/). 
The error message is:

> "Warning:  file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect.
>   File(/data/web/virtuals/115731/virtual/www/wp-content/themes/bellevue/dynamic.css)
>   is not within the allowed path(s): (/data/web/virtuals/137976/virtual)
>   in
>   /data/web/virtuals/137976/virtual/www/wp-content/themes/bellevue/option-tree/includes/ot-functions.php
>   on line 238
>   (/data/web/virtuals/115731/virtual/www/wp-content/themes/bellevue/dynamic.css)

Line 238 of the specified file is:

```
if ( '' != $path && file_exists( $path ) ) {
      $parts = explode( '/wp-content', $path );
      if ( isset( $parts[1] ) ) {
        $css = set_url_scheme( WP_CONTENT_URL ) . $parts[1];
        if ( $last_css !== $css ) {
          /* enqueue filtered file */
          wp_enqueue_style( 'ot-dynamic-' . $key, $css, false, OT_VERSION );
          $last_css = $css;
```

Could you please suggest what the problem might be?
Thank you very much for any ideas (I've been trying to figure this out for hours)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the absolute path is set up somewhere - maybe at the db.

Because of this, Wordpress on the new account tries to load the file from the old account.
You need to find every place where the old path `/data/web/virtuals/115731/` is defined and replace it with the new path:
`/data/web/virtuals/137976/`

Comment: Dear @chrwhm, your answer was very helpful. I'm facing the very same issue again. Could you please specify how did you find out what the new path should be - the new number?